# upload multiple images into different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, file-upload

I have two buttons, which I want both to upload two different files and display these inside of two different divs. My code works fine for 1 image. How do I modify the code to be able to handle 2 images? Thanks!

My code at the moment is:

HTML:

```
<div class="span12">
    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file"> Browse 1 <input type="file" onchange="readURL(this);"></span>
            <span class="btn btn-default btn-file"> Browse 2 <input type="file" onchange="readURL(this);"></span>

    <div class="place-image" id="myimage">
    <div class= "place-content" id="myimage2" onkeypress="return (this.innerText.length <= 16)">
            <p contenteditable="true">SALE<br>40%</p>
            </div>  
        </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#myimage').css('background', 'transparent url('+e.target.result +') left top no-repeat');
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: add an attribute multiple to your input type ="file" it should look like <input id="imgReader" type="file" multiple="multiple" name="photo"> and then in jquery create an input change event $('input').change(function() { and loop through this.files.length

Answer (score 0):

Add `data-preview="preview_div_id"` to each `input`. Then in the `onload` function you should replace `$('#myimage')` with `$('#' + $(input).data("preview"))`.

Like this:

```
<div class="span12">
    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file"> Browse 1 <input type="file" onchange="readURL(this);" data-preview="myimage"></span>
            <span class="btn btn-default btn-file"> Browse 2 <input type="file" onchange="readURL(this);" data-preview="myimage2"></span>

    <div class="place-image" id="myimage">
    <div class= "place-content" id="myimage2" onkeypress="return (this.innerText.length <= 16)">
            <p contenteditable="true">SALE<br>40%</p>
            </div>  
        </div>


<script>
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#' + $(input).data("preview")).css('background', 'transparent url('+e.target.result +') left top no-repeat');
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Diego! It works perfectly. Really appreciate it.